# JSON data is showing null after publishing my app on google play

Tags: java, json, android-studio

JSON data is showing null after publishing my app on google play, But it shows the data in the emulator while running the non published app sourcecode. The data is coming from the Database online from external server.The json data is visible in the URL, But is shows null in my published app. What could be the reason??.....

PLEASE HELP ME

This is my MainActivity

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JUR extends AppCompatActivity implements jurAdapter.JURAdapterListener {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private List<JURlist> jurList;
    private jurAdapter mAdapter;
    private SearchView searchView;
    ProgressBar progressBar2;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("keys");
    }
    public native String getJUR();
    public native String geturl2();

    String getJUR = URLEncoder.encode(getJUR());
    String geturl2 = URLEncoder.encode(geturl2());

    // url to fetch contacts json
    private  final String URL = "https://"+geturl2+"/...../"+getJUR;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jur);
        progressBar2 = findViewById(R.id.progress2);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toolbar toolbar2 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);

        // toolbar fancy stuff
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.toolbar_JUR);

        recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        jurList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new jurAdapter(this, jurList, this);

        // white background notification bar
        whiteNotificationBar(recyclerView2);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView2.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView2.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, 36));
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        fetchJUR();
    }

    /**
     * fetches json by making http calls
     */
    private void fetchJUR() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch JURISDICTION Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        List<JURlist> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<JURlist>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        // adding contacts to contacts list
                        jurList.clear();
                        jurList.addAll(items);

                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error in getting json
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        APP.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // close search view on back button pressed
        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    private void whiteNotificationBar(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onJURSelected(JURlist jur) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: " + jur.getSTATE() + ", " + jur.getZONE(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

This is the Adapter

````
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class jurAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<jurAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<JURlist> JuRlist;
    private List<JURlist> JURlistFiltered;
    private JURAdapterListener listener;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView STATE, ZONE, COM, DIVI, RANAME, RANGE1;
//        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            STATE = view.findViewById(R.id.STATE);
            ZONE = view.findViewById(R.id.ZONE);
            COM = view.findViewById(R.id.COM);
            DIVI = view.findViewById(R.id.DIVI);
            RANAME = view.findViewById(R.id.RANAME);
            RANGE1 = view.findViewById(R.id.RANGE1);


//            thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listener.onJURSelected(JURlistFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public jurAdapter(Context context, List<JURlist> JURLIST, JURAdapterListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.JuRlist = JURLIST;
        this.JURlistFiltered = JURLIST;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent1, int viewType1) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent1.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.jur_item_row, parent1, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        final JURlist jurlist = JURlistFiltered.get(position);
        holder.STATE.setText("STATE : "+jurlist.getSTATE()+"\r\n") ;
        holder.ZONE.setText("ZONE : "+jurlist.getZONE()+"\r\n");
        holder.COM.setText("COMMISSIONERATE NAME : "+jurlist.getCOM()+"\r\n");
        holder.DIVI.setText("DIVISION NAME : "+jurlist.getDIVI()+"\r\n");
        holder.RANAME.setText("RANGE NAME : "+jurlist.getRANAME()+"\r\n");
        holder.RANGE1.setText("RANGE JURISDICTION : \r\n"+jurlist.getRANGE1());

//        Glide.with(context)
//                .load(contact.getImage())
//                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
//                .into(holder.thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return JURlistFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    JURlistFiltered = JuRlist;
                } else {
                    List<JURlist> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (JURlist row : JuRlist) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getSTATE().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||  row.getZONE().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||  row.getCOM().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||  row.getDIVI().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||  row.getRANAME().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||  row.getRANGE1().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    JURlistFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = JURlistFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                JURlistFiltered = (ArrayList<JURlist>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface JURAdapterListener {
        void onJURSelected(JURlist jur);
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWmG.jpg
````

Comment: Is url for this `The data is coming from the phpMyAdmin Database online from external server` public facing?

Comment: yes it is Public Facing